# mysql select ... in , count several match relevance

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to do a 'similar posts' mysql string, all my posts have tags, so I am trying with this query:

```
SELECT articles.id,title,cover_image 
FROM articles 
INNER JOIN article_tags ON (article_tags.article_id = articles.id) 
WHERE  article_tags.tag_id 
IN (312,13016,109,120,1493,103,1667,13015,331,5,564,13014,1670,113,13045) 
AND articles.id <> 88230
```

it does the job somehow, but the problem is the posts are not really relevant to the original post,
for example if one tag is 'cool', then i would get any post with tag cool

ideally, what i want is to sort these results by how many occurrences of tags there are,
for example:

```
article 1 has tags: tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4, tag5
article 2 has tags: tag2, tag3, tag4,
article 3 has tags: tag1, tag4
article 4 has tags: tag1, tag2, tag4, tag5
```

so I'd like sql to return this set of results:

tag1,tag4, tag2, tag3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track.  Just use `group by` to find the number of matches and order by that:

```
SELECT articles.id, title, cover_image 
FROM articles INNER JOIN
     article_tags
     ON article_tags.article_id = articles.id
WHERE article_tags.tag_id IN (312,13016,109,120,1493,103,1667,13015,331,5,564,13014,1670,113,13045) AND
      articles.id <> 88230 
GROUP BY articles.id,title, cover_image
ORDER BY count(*) DESC;
```

You can include `count(*) as NumMatches` in the `select` as well.

Comment: ah great, thanks! group by always somehow confused me, i've just used it to get unique entries on joins...btw, how can i make the above query select 4 randomly from the top 10 results for example?

Comment: @roynaufal . . . Selecting four randomly from the top 10 is really a different question.